# Debug exe in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging

Is there a way to debug external exe using visual studio 2010 by shift+double click to run the exe.  Normally, to run the application in a special mode we have press the shift and double click the exe, but I have a bug that happens right on start up and I guess I need to add a command line argument to get it into that mode.  I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically you want to attach debugger as soon as the process starts. This should help. Source http://blogs.msdn.com/b/greggm/archive/2005/02/21/377663.aspx

- Run regedit.exe
- Goto HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows
  NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options
- Create a new key for your exe (example: foo.exe)
- Create a new string value under your exe. The name of the string
  value is 'Debugger', and the value is 'vsjitdebugger.exe'

Answer (score 0):

If I understand enough of that, you want to debug a program not launched by VS.. In vs pro+ you can select "debug" and then "Attach to process" so you would start your applicaiton and then can attach to it.

Comment: I dont think I explained it well. In visual studio you can go to the project properties and debug tab set the start external program.  In the command linke arguements I need to do the same as shift double click on an exe outside of visual studio.   Example when I am in windows explorer I hold the shift key and double click on the exe.  I cant attach to the process because the error happens before the app loads fully.